# How to list (and re-try) failed mounts with systemd

Tags: linux, mount, systemd

I have some mount points that failed loading due to missing dependencies (a underlying file system wasn't decrypted yet). A `systemctl status <mountpoint>` shows the following:

```
root@mymachine:/sharedfolders# systemctl status /sharedfolders/Multimedia
● sharedfolders-Multimedia.mount - Mount shared folder Multimedia to /sharedfolders/Multimedia
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sharedfolders-Multimedia.mount; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
    Where: /sharedfolders/Multimedia
     What: /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/Multimedia

Jul 09 19:13:58 mymachine systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Mount shared folder Multimedia to /sharedfolders/Multimedia.
Jul 09 19:13:58 mymachine systemd[1]: sharedfolders-Multimedia.mount: Job sharedfolders-Multimedia.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'
```

Is there a `systemctl` command that would list me such failed mount attempts and ideally re-try them all?

I tried `systemctl --failed` but didn't see those mounts in the list.
All other commands I've found so far need me to specify the mount point, which is precisely what I actually want to know from the system in the first place.

*Bonus question*: Is there a systemd-way of triggering those re-tries automatically? I mean the dependency is clearly documented in the mount unit and mount of the (then decrypted) dependency is also done via systemd, so it COULD know to re-try those depedend mounts.

Answer (score 7):

I've found

```
systemctl list-units -t mount --all | grep inactive |grep loaded |grep sharedfolders |grep -o "/.*" | xargs systemctl start
```

so far, which is quite ugly and still needs to be manually called or added to cron. I hope there is a better solution.

I'll explain the commands:

- `-t mounts` limits the list of systemd units to mounts
- `--all` also shows the failed ones
- `grep inactive` reduces the list to JUST the failed ones
- `grep loaded` limits the list to those units that are at least
  functional (e.g. not 'not-found')
- `grep sharedfolders` limits the list to mount points specific to my
  use case
- `grep -o "/.*"` shortens the output to just the path of the mount
  point
- `xargs systemctl start` sends the remaining items as arguments to
  systemctl start, which mounts them (again)

Answer (score 1):

I modified Chaos_99 approach to also allow "failed" systemctl entries (not only inactive), because if already tried, its status is not inactive but failed (it happens for example after this: "systemctl restart storage-music.mount").

Therefore:

```
#List all failed mount attempts and retry them
tries=0
MAX_TRIES=10
while [[ $tries -lt $MAX_TRIES ]]; do

   NOTMOUNTED=`systemctl list-units -t mount --all | grep 'inactive\|failed' | grep loaded | grep storage |grep -o -w 'storage-.*.mount' | cut -d' ' -f1 | wc -l`
   if [ $NOTMOUNTED == 0 ] ; then
      echo "All shared folders perfectly mounted"
      break
   fi
   echo "Trying to mount shared folders again"

   systemctl list-units -t mount --all | grep 'failed\|inactive' |grep loaded | grep storage |grep -o -w  "storage-.*.mount" | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -r systemctl restart
   sleep 10
   tries=$((tries+1))
done
```

Differences with respect to previous answer:

- `while [[ $tries -lt $MAX_TRIES...`  It tries 10 times, wait 10 seconds between attempts, and exits as soon as it is all ok.
- `grep 'inactive\|failed'`  greps not only inactive but also failed shares
- `cut -d' ' -f1` takes only 1st word or entry
- `wc -l`  Counts how many entries, if everything is properly mounted it returns 0

I hope it helps.